# Rails 5 association with different foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, rails-activerecord

I think I have missed something when creating an association with a foreign_key in Rails.

I have 2 models: `Company` and `Employee`. Company `has_many` employees and Employee `belongs_to` a company. `Company` has an attribute called `company_code` and I should be able to figure out which company the employee works for using the `company_code` instead of `company_id`.

At first, I created the models:

```
rails g model Company company_code:integer:index name

rails g model Employee joined:date:index salary:integer
```

Then, I generated a migration to add the `company_code` column to the `employees` table.

```
class AddReferenceToEmployee < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :employees, :company_code, :integer, index: true
    add_foreign_key :employees, :companies, column: :company_code
  end
end
```

And, finally I added the foreign key at the model level.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees, foreign_key: :company_code
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, foreign_key: :company_code
end
```

However, I'm still not able to create proper association.

```
company = Company.create(name: 'test', company_code: 123)
company.employees.create(joined: Date.today, salary: 1000)
```

It creates employee record with `company_code = 1` instead of 123.

When I try to create a new instance of employee

```
company.employees.new
```

It will generate

```
#<Employee id: nil, joined: nil, salary: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, company_code: 1>
```

What am I missing? Is this the right way to do it?

Bellow is my `schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180828052633) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "company_code"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_code"], name: "index_company_on_company_code"
  end

  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "joined"
    t.integer "salary"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "company_code"
  end

  add_foreign_key "employees", "companies", column: "company_code"
end
```

Comment: Try `belongs_to :company, foreign_key: :company_code, primary_key: :company_code`

Comment: What's inside your db/schema.rb?

Comment: What is this `statistics` now?

Comment: Sorry was trying with different models. Updated with `schema.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees, primary_key: :company_code, foreign_key: :company_code
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, foreign_key: :company_code, primary_key: :company_code
end
```